# PREVIEW - Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 (API 23) Gapps

Tags: android, genymotion, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there is some Gapps flashable zip, that works with PREVIEW - Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 (API 23)  on Genymotion?

I have tried

```
Slim_zero_gapps.BETA.6.0.build.0.x-20151008a
gapps-600-base-20151009-2-signed
benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3
```

and few others but only benzo succeed in flashing. Using benzo Google apps crash because of missing some *.so files.

Do any one succeeded in  flashing gapps into PREVIEW - Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 (API 23) and can tell which gapps package is working?

**Update for some "Professionals"** 
Negative votes requires explanation or solution!

Comment: Is your Genymotion device ARMEABI compatible? AFAIK, Genymotion usually runs in x86 instead of ARM mode which is why some of the .so/APK files are being rejected due to INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE

Make sure you have the ARM translation
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: There is no information about that in description.

Comment: Ohh that explains a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After some testing last night, I managed to get the Play store up and running:

1. first flashed the [Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23252070760974384),
2. then flashed the [gapps-L-4-21-15.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406),
3. restarted the virtual machine,
4. signed in to my Google account (while a few play service errors did pop up),
5. flashed [benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347835438),
6. restarted the virtual machine and it was up and running.

Comment: Fixed that, explained in depth how I got google apps to run on the preview

Comment: Make sure that play services and the store have all permissions enable though.

Comment: After many attempts at getting gapps installed on one of the Preview emulators, adding the gapps-L-4-21-15.zip to the sequence of installation finally solved it.  Thank you.

Comment: Where from we can download gapps-L-4-21-15.zip ? Is it correct url http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/gapps/5.1/gapps-L-4-21-15.zip ?

Comment: This process works, sometimes there is error for google play services but generally it works. BTW, I am using benzo-gapps-M-20151202-signed.zip

Comment: Can't add google account, I always get `unfortunately google play services has stopped`, custom phone api 23, Genymotion 2.8.0 (I guess it just doesn't work anymore with the latest ver. of Genymotion

Comment: After step 3 I'm in a reboot /install loop, with the Hyper-V Android Emulator. Anyone else encountering this problem?

Answer (score 3):

[solved] Wow gapps-L-4-21-15.zip finally let Play Store to start without play services errors on Preview Nexus 6P (after a second reboot)

Comment: Since i asked how to solve Google Nexus 5X  flashing problem, i can't accept this answer. BUT with 6P it works flawless. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to flash this one purenexus-gapps-mm-20151014.zip flawless but I have issues with Google Play Services.

Comment: That one didn't flashed successfully for me.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to find play services for your device opengapps.org. Choose x86 for genymotion